# Tumblr HTML web page

Tags: html, tumblr, tumblr-html

I made a page out of Tumblr. But I'm having an issue with removing these two.

The website is at " autoproparts.co " under products/brake disc.

Could someone please advise me on how to fix it? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Understood...I'll post a better one again ..thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Delete

```
<div class="post-entry">
```

and

```
<div class="post-share [...]>
```

Sections.

What I did was 'inspect' those elements in Chrome to find which bit of code they were.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try like u instructed.